# Pivot table columns with same values

Tags: pivot-table

I have a pivot table where by the two columns are showing me same values instead of showing the respective value.
The 2nd column (Count of Financial Eligibility) is not reflecting it's own values.
How do i fix this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paICg.png)

My first column (Count of Business Eligibility) column type is string where as the 2nd column (Count of Financial Eligibility) column type is an integer.